# How dynamically add/delete textViews to/from linearLayout?

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout, dynamically-generated

I have db with name of countries(for example).
My first goal is dynamically add textView for (each country) to linearLayout `(android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent")`. In fact adding is not a problem, but problem if the orientation of layout is `horizontal` and there is to much countries, but the width of layout is not enough to show all of them and they are hide!

So i need to add textViews dynamically, but if there is not enough space for new textView - add it in the next line or create new linearLayout.

I need to create new textView for each country cos than i want to make clickListener for each of them, and there is second goal...

the second goal is delete some of that textView by clicking on it, and the other textView must relocate to that empty space.
Hope that my explanation is clear :) if not i will try another one.

so, i have idea how to add textView: every time when i add new textView - count the length of all previously added ones with this one and compare it with length of linearLayout, if the length of all textViews is less - add to this linLayout, else - create new lin layout and add textView there.
I think this could work, it it looks ugly :)
I hope there are must be more simply and pretty solution!

Talking about dynamically deleting textViews from layout - I have no idea how to do this correctly.

So I will be glad any solutions and ideas, thanks!

**EDIT**
here is example how I want it looks like in the end:[image]

Comment: Make use of ScrollView

Comment: @Sridhar, that is not solution!

Comment: What you're describing is what `ListView` / `RecyclerView` does out of the box. Use that.

Comment: @LudoBagman Why did you tell that adding scrollview is not a solution? There are many solution for your problem like using listview or something, try to solve it step by step, And also show your effort here will be better.

Comment: To echo @Barend - everything you've described can be achieved with greater simplicity and infinitely better efficiency with either a `ListView` or `RecyclerView`. There is no need to concern yourself with manually adding or deleting `TextView`s. In addition, `TextView`s should auto word-wrap anyway, so there is no need to create a separate `TextView` for each line.

Comment: @Barend, it is add only one country for listItem, and in this case it spend a lot of space

Comment: @PPartisan, yep, you are right, but I need to add all countries not on by one to another row

Comment: @PPartisan, maybe my knowledge about RecyclerView and listView is not enough, and if there is some solution how my goals can be finished with them - please give some example

Comment: @LudoBagman I think at this stage it would help to see a picture and/or some code you have tried for what you are trying to achieve. Nothing you have said so far contradicts the idea that `ListView`/`RecyclerView` would suit your situation

Comment: @PPartisan, ok, i will add some picture and than write to you. thanks

Comment: I think I now understand what you're looking for. A `RecyclerView` with a `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` [javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html), [source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java) comes pretty close, but it makes you pick a fixed number of columns. If you want to pack the contents even tighter, with each row as many columns as fit, I think you're looking at writing your own `RecyclerView.LayoutManager`.

Comment: @Barend please take a look for my updated question with picture.
Thanks

Comment: @PPartisan,
i have not enough experience with recyclerView. can you give an example how it can be provided in my case (please take a look of a pic in the question how it must look in the end) ?? Thanks

Comment: you can use flexbox-layout

Answer (score 2):

LinearLayout is usually used for fixed childs.

For dynamic and large number of childs, you should use `ListView` or `RecyclerView`, which is exactly designed for what you described.

More than that, `ListView` and `RecyclerView` can reuse the child views, i.e. TextView for your case, which is needed, because view objects are heavy to create and keep in memory.

**Edit:**

Given your image and replies in comment. I would suggest you to use TextView with ClickableSpan, and set update the whole Text on click.

You can check ClickableSpan in the link below.

http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.text.style.ClickableSpan

Comment: i have not enough experience with recyclerView. can you give an example how it can be provided in my case (please take a look of a pic in the question how it must look in the end) ?? Thanks

Comment: Do you need each item to be clickable? From your image, I would suggest you simply use a TextView, it is very difficult to have line wrapping with Views and may not be needed for your case.

Comment: yep, every item must be clickable, and if it was clicked - it must be deleted from layout, and all other must move aside.

Comment: updated my answer, you need to use ClickableSpan in TextView

Comment: Thanks!
Spannable is new for me, pretty cool solution! but it's still not exactly what I need. I need each of item a separated View

Answer (score 0):

You can use flowlayout for that. Link for flowlayout is https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout. Just inflate your views inside flowlayout. You don't have to do any calculation when inflating. If there is space available for textviews then they will be added horizontally else in the next line.